# jena.query.ResultSet and jena.query.QuerySolution: hasNext() returns alway false after SPARQL request

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I have a problem with receiving `SPARQL` response.
The problem is .... when I use the following source code, `rs.hasNext()` always return false even though the response shouldn't be empty.

SPARQL Query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
SELECT ?s ?sl <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?o ?ol
FROM <http://en.dbpedia.org/20120601/>
WHERE {
    ?s rdfs:label ?sl .
    ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?o .
    ?o rdfs:label ?ol .
FILTER (   lang(?sl)= "en"  &&  lang(?ol)= "en"  ) }
LIMIT 100
```

This query works correctly in `DBPedia` `Endpoint`.

This query was executed using `Jena` as below.

Soucre Code:

```
...

            QueryEngineHTTP qexec = new QueryEngineHTTP("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query));
            // "query" is as above
            qexec.addDefaultGraph(http://en.dbpedia.org/20120601/);
            List<QuerySolution> resultSetList = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>();

            ResultSet rs = qexec.execSelect();

            while (rs.hasNext())
                resultSetList.add(rs.next());

            if (!resultSetList.isEmpty()) {
                if (query.contains("?o rdfs:label ?ol")) {
                    func...1
                    func...2
                }
                else {
                    func...3
                    func...4
                }
            }
            else {
                qexec.close();
                break;
            }

...
```

There is no problem in `SPARQL` `Endpoint` because I could get the result from `SPARQL` `Query`.
However, I couldn't get any result using `Jena`.
As I mentioned, `rs.hasNext()` always return `false` even though the response shouldn't be `empty`.
What would be the resolution for that `rs.hasNext()` doesn't work, and things cannot be added to `resultSetList`?

I think the way of using `Jena` is fine... Is there something wrong?

Comment: Be aware that `lang(?sl)= "en"  &&  lang(?ol)= "en"` isn't really the right way to compare language tags.  Use, e.g., `langMatches(lang(?sl),"en")`.

Comment: Also, your query isn't *legal* for one thing.  I wouldn't be surprised if Jena does something unexpected with it.  You can't put a URI reference in the list of projection variables like that, even if Virtuoso doesn't complain about it.  You can validate your query with [sparql.org's validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide a *complete* and minimal example, so it's hard to see exactly what's going wrong in your code.  You query doesn't even parse with Jena, so I'm not sure why you're not simply getting an error, as opposed to an empty result set.  Here's a minimal example that uses your query:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;

public class DBpediaExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "" +
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "SELECT ?s ?sl <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?o ?ol\n" +
                "FROM <http://en.dbpedia.org/20120601/>\n" +
                "WHERE {\n" +
                "  ?s rdfs:label ?sl .\n" +
                "  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?o .\n" +
                "  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .\n" +
                "  FILTER (   lang(?sl)= \"en\"  &&  lang(?ol)= \"en\"  )\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "LIMIT 100";
        ResultSet rs = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query ).execSelect();

        while ( rs.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( rs.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Encountered " <IRIref> "<http://dbpedia.org/property/name> "" at line 3, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    <VAR1> ...
    <VAR2> ...
    "from" ...
    "where" ...
    "(" ...
    "{" ...

    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.perform(ParserSPARQL11.java:102)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserSPARQL11.parse$(ParserSPARQL11.java:53)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.SPARQLParser.parse(SPARQLParser.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.parse(QueryFactory.java:139)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:79)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(QueryExecutionFactory.java:358)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(QueryExecutionFactory.java:345)
    at DBpediaExample.main(DBpediaExample.java:19)
```

You can't use a URI reference in the projection variables like you have, even if Virtuoso accepts it.  It's not legal SPARQL, and you can check using [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query).

I'm not sure why you're using the `FROM` in your query, but if you actually put that IRI into to the public endpoint's "Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)" field, you don't get any results.  Perhaps you want to query the standard data set instead?

As an additional issue, you should really be comparing language tags using `langMatches`.

If you fix those problems, you'd end up with the following query and code, which shows plenty of results.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;

public class DBpediaExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = "" +
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "SELECT ?s ?sl (<http://dbpedia.org/property/name> as ?p) ?o ?ol\n" +
                "WHERE {\n" +
                "  ?s rdfs:label ?sl .\n" +
                "  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ?o .\n" +
                "  ?o rdfs:label ?ol .\n" +
                "  FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?sl),'en') && langMatches(lang(?ol),'en') )\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "LIMIT 100";
        ResultSet rs = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query ).execSelect();

        while ( rs.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( rs.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

```
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1990–91 NOFV-Oberliga"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1990%E2%80%9391_NOFV-Oberliga> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jens_Dowe> ) ( ?ol = "Jens Dowe"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1. FC Heidenheim"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1._FC_Heidenheim> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kevin_Kraus> ) ( ?ol = "Kevin Kraus"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1905–06 FC Barcelona season"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1905%E2%80%9306_FC_Barcelona_season> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Carles_Comamala> ) ( ?ol = "Carles Comamala"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1910–11 FC Barcelona season"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1910%E2%80%9311_FC_Barcelona_season> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Carles_Comamala> ) ( ?ol = "Carles Comamala"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1910–11 FC Barcelona season"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1910%E2%80%9311_FC_Barcelona_season> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Francisco_Bru> ) ( ?ol = "Francisco Bru"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1. FC Heidenheim"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1._FC_Heidenheim> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Thurk> ) ( ?ol = "Michael Thurk"@en )
( ?p = <http://dbpedia.org/property/name> ) ( ?sl = "1990–91 NOFV-Oberliga"@en ) ( ?s = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/1990%E2%80%9391_NOFV-Oberliga> ) ( ?o = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hilmar_Weilandt> ) ( ?ol = "Hilmar Weilandt"@en )
…
```