# jena.query.ResultSet: hasNext() evaluates false but should contain something

Tags: java, sparql, jena, virtuoso

I try to query dbpedia 3.9 datasets on virtuoso (local, 7.0.0).
The query works fine on the SPARQL endpoint, but when using Jena, the ResultSet from the virtuoso query execution does not contain nothing (hasNext() is false). I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867499/jena-query-resultset-and-jena-query-querysolution-hasnext-returns-alway-false) and [here](http://ehc.ac/p/virtuoso/mailman/message/31494803/), but I still have the pb.

Below the code I am using.
Would someone have an idea of what's wrong?

Thanks.

```
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtGraph;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecution;
import virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;

public static void testDbpediaLex(Resource dbpedia)
{

    String query = " PREFIX  lexvo: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#> \n"
            + " PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n\n"
            + " SELECT ?lexlabel WHERE { \n"
            + " <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> lexvo:label ?lexlabel . \n"
            + " <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> rdf:label ?label . \n"
            + " FILTER (?lexlabel != ?label) .  } ";

    VirtGraph graph = new VirtGraph ("http://dbpedia.org/", "jdbc:virtuoso://localhost:1111", "dba", "dba");

    VirtuosoQueryExecution vqLex = VirtuosoQueryExecutionFactory.create(query, graph);
    ResultSet rLex = VirtuosoConnection.executeVirtuosoQuery(vqLex);
    if(rLex != null)
    {
        while (rLex.hasNext())
        {
            QuerySolution result = rLex.nextSolution();
            System.out.println(result.get("lexlabel"));
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're asking about triples with the subject `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso>`, can you show us the results of `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> ?p ?o`.  Using that, we can make a better guess about what your query will return.

Comment: Three immediate notes:  (i) the typical prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#` is `rdfs:`.  It won't change the meaning of the query, but people will probably see yours (`rdf:`) and expect that you've got a typo.  (ii) Comparing labels may be complicated by language tags.  The behavior of `!=` may match more things than you expect (or not, this is just a thought).  (iii)  This doesn't look like complete code.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see any declaration of `i`, yet your loop includes `i++`.   It's easier to help with code that we can actually compile and run.

Comment: @Joshua, thanks a lot for your comments. I will fix (i), I will restrict on label@en only (ii) and yes, I removed some part of the code and forgot that one, sorry (iii). Regarding the main problem of the ResultSet being empty, I found out my mistake: DBpedia lexicalization dataset is a named graph and this should be made explicit in the query (`GRAPH ?g { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> lexvo:label ?lexlabel }`). There was some discrepancies regarding graph datasets between my query via Jena and the one via sparql endpoint, and I did not notice this immediately.

Comment: @ehrmama If you've figured out your own answer you can post it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to the pb, here come some more details.

With the following sparql query I want to get the labels of a given resource (whatever), as defined via the properties `rdfs:label` and `lexvo:label`. The first one applies on triples (dbpedia label dataset), the second on quads (dbpedia spotlight lexicalization dataset).

```
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX  lexvo: <http://lexvo.org/ontology#>

SELECT  ?lexlabel
WHERE
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> lexvo:label ?lexlabel .
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> rdfs:label ?label
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en")
    FILTER langMatches(lang(?lexlabel), "en")
    FILTER ( ?lexlabel != ?label )
  }
```

On the local sparql endpoint (virtuoso.ini) the default graph is not specified. The Graph IRI on the sparql endpoint is therefore empty, and the query works well under these conditions.

Using the Virtuoso Jena Provider, `VirtGraph` is defined with the graph `http://dbpedia.org`, and in this case the query does not give result. Indeed, the same happens when specifying `http://dbpedia.org` in the Graph IRI field of the sparql endpoint, that was my mistake of not checking this.

Finally, to retrieve the results via Jena (i.e. using the `VirtGraph` with `http://dbpedia.org`), the query should specify the graph's dataset when needed:

```
SELECT ?lexlabel WHERE 
{
GRAPH ?g {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> lexvo:label ?lexlabel . }
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fernando_Alonso> rdfs:label ?label .  
FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en"))
FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?lexlabel), "en"))
FILTER (?lexlabel != ?label) .  }
```

which gives following labels: "Alonso"@en, "Fernando"@en and "Alo"@en.

Comment: If this is a solution and it worked for you, then you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).  If this is just the information that I asked for in a comment on the question, then you should *edit* the question with this additional information.